# TextInput fullheight and Button in bottom

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a simple note app with react native.
I want TextInput full height, can scroll, have paper background(i think have to repeat background like css, but resizeMode: 'repeat' is not working).
And a Button in bottom. Please help.

Below image is my current layout:

[image]
This is layout which I want:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<View>
    <ScrollView
      style={{flex: 1}}
    >
    <ImageBackground 
      style={{
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        resizeMode: 'repeat',
        flex: 1
      }}
      source={require('../assets/images/paper-bg.png')}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          fontSize: 18,
          lineHeight: 25,
          flex: 1,
          padding: 3,
        }}
        multiline = {true}
        numberOfLines = {4}
        placeholder="Hãy viết gì đó" />
    </ImageBackground>
    </ScrollView>

    <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={0.95}
          onPress={() => this.onSaveButtonPress()} 
            style ={{
                height: 40,
                width:160,
                borderRadius:4,
                backgroundColor : "#2980b9",
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#ebebeb',
                color: "#ffffff",
                flex: 1
            }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: 'white',
            textAlign: 'center',
            lineHeight: 38,
            fontSize: 18,
          }}
        >
        Tên nút</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity> 
    </View>
  </View>
```

I'm newbie in react native, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resizeMode: repeat is not working on Ios,

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/image#resizemode

I can't see your layouts, but you can try to play with width and height both on your background and textinput and I suppose you can reach what you are trying to do by this way,

You can use Dimensions to get width and height of the device for a dynamic background.

```
  const screenWidth = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width);
const screenHeight = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').height);
```